# Postgres, Create uniqueness of values between 2 columns

Tags: mysql, postgresql

and thank you ahead of time for anyone able to help.  I have this table shown below.

Table INVOICE

---

id| delivery_statement_id     | supply_statement_id

_ | 1                         |2

_ | 3                         |4

_ | 2 | 4      <-Should not pass to DB because id 2 already used in first row.

I want to make sure that unique ids exists between 2 columns throughout the entire database

If statement_id 1 has been used it can never be used again for delivery, or supply statement. 
Please help, when I search this issue I keep getting index for multiple columns but that only solves issues of row combinations.

Thank you

Comment: Are you generating the id tags, or taking them as input from another source?

Comment: If you are referring to the ids of delivery and statement I am taking the values from the database.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, that you have a table of the following structure:

```
"invoice"
(
id (primary key),
delivery_statement_id,
supply_statement_id
)
```

Judging from the names of the colums, "delivery_statement_id" and "supply_statement_id" are foreign keys to the same, external table... let's say, they refer to "statement"

```
"invoice"
(
id (primary key),
delivery_statement_id -> statement(id),
supply_statement_id -> statement(id)
)
```

If you have a table "statement" and you want to avoid having multiple references from "delivery_statement_id" and "supply_statement_id" - my advise would be to add "invoice_id" column to the "statement" table:

```
"statement"
(
id (primary key),
/** some other columns **/
invoice_id (nullable, with unique constraint) -> invoice(id)
)
```

so first you create rows in "statement" without a reference to any invoice
then you set delivery_statement_id and supply_statement_id
and after setting each value you must "register" it in the "statement" table... this can be easily implemented as a trigger, attached to "invoice" table

Comment: Hi Voycheck, you definitely understood the problem correctly but I see an error occurring with making invoice_id in statement table.  Two statement will always point to one invoice so the unique constraint will fail.  I beileve the better workaround is to leave statement_id in the invoice table and just have each differentiate as delivery or supply within the statement table.  This would be achieved by creating attribute type, or something like boolean delivery_statement (and if false than its a supply statement).